# what is wrong with trailing white space in typeScript?

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code

I know that this is due to linting but I'm just curious what is wrong with having trailing spaces?

I will be turning this feature of with tslint.json but before I do so, I'd like to make sure I'm not shooting myself in the foot.

As you know, VS-Code does show wavy underlines when a trailing space is detected. I prefer not to. 
My justification is ... at the time of transpiling or for-sure in deployment, those trailing spaces are taken down anyway, so what's the worry?

Comment: The worry is more about making sure you write consistent tidy code. It makes you look a little lazy when you don't clean up after yourself. The diffs can be a problem too, but most diff viewers have an option to ignore whitespace

Answer (score 7):

> This is a linting guidance but I'm just curious what is wrong with having trailing spaces?

They are useless stuff that causes git diffing / git logs when there is actually no significant change in the file.

> At the time of transpiling, aren't those trailing spaces are taken down anyway?

Yes.

## More

You are free to commit empty spaces if this is what you want. Linting is just good guidance.

Comment: That's great. I just did `"no-trailing-whitespace": false,` at tslint.json. Boy what a relief!

Comment: You could also set  `"files.trimTrailingWhitespace": true` in your VS Code config. The editor will trim every time you hit save. IMO this is the best way to deal with this.

Comment: that's one notch smarter.